# 'Earth-based' adjective counterpart to 'Lunar' or 'Solar'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

We have adjectives relating to various celestial bodies: 'Solar', 'Lunar', 'Martian', 'Venusian' etc. What would be the counterpart to Earth? 'Earthian' sounds very awkward to me... is it valid?

For example, the situation where Earth is eclipsed by a celestial body on the visual path between the observer and Earth, what would be the counterpart to 'Solar eclipse' and 'Lunar eclipse'?

Comment: According to _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003), the first meaning of **terrestrial** is "of or relating to the earth or its inhabitants." Does that fit the meaning you have in mind?

Comment: @SvenYargs: If a celestial body goes between the observer and Earth, obscuring it, is it terrestrial eclipse?

Comment: Terrestrial eclipse. https://www.google.it/search?q=terrestrial+eclipse&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1uPao3NLbAhVHK8AKHRvsCuwQsAQIOA&biw=941&bih=525

Comment: From Dominic Ford, [_The Observer's Guide to Planetary Motion_](https://books.google.com/books?id=1kUkBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&dq=%22terrestrial+eclipse%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgrYfe29LbAhVrwFQKHVQ7AeEQ6AEISzAG#v=onepage&q=%22terrestrial%20eclipse%22&f=false) (2014): "Likewise, what we call a solar eclipse on Earth might reasonably be called a **terrestrial eclipse** on the Moon." Ford is by no means alone in taking this view, as a search for "terrestrial eclipse" in Google Books (also suggested by user110518) will confirm.

Comment: ngram shows some 'earth eclipse'; none for 'terran' or 'terrestrial eclipse'; the google images are all incorrect, as it's solar eclipse caused by Earth - by convention 'eclipse' takes the body eclipsed, not the one eclipsing. (otherwise what we call 'lunar eclipse' would be called 'terrestrial eclipse', and 'solar eclipse' would be 'lunar eclipse').

Comment: @SF. - sorry, what is your question exactly? is it about eclipses? https://www.quora.com/Can-we-see-terrestrial-eclipse-from-the-Moon

Comment: @user1105178  It's about the adjective that goes with it. I'm skeptical of answers that yield [562](https://www.google.it/search?q="terrestrial+eclipse") and [350](https://www.google.it/search?q="terran+eclipse") hits from Google and 0 on ngram, and image results don't conform to the regular usage of this sort of phrase - unlike [this photo](http://www.myconfinedspace.com/2015/08/11/the-far-side-of-the-moon/nasa-pic-of-earth-and-moon-from-l1-point-1926x1080-wallpaper-png-2/) which presents actual partial [terran|terrestrial|??] eclipse.

Comment: I suggest you make your question clear. If you are specifically looking for the more appropriate adjective in the specific case of an eclipse, you should mention that or probably ask on the astronomy site.

Comment: @SF I guess the point is that a terrestrial eclipse is what you would see from the moon when from the earth you would observe a solar eclipse. You would see the shadow of the moon moving over part of the earth. A full eclipse would be impossible.

Comment: Oops, I added a comment to this extent to the linked quora answer, which resulted in a "oops" and a removal of the answer and picture. Sorry...

Comment: Nobody has suggested "Earthling" yet. I believe there was a time (1940s to 1960s) when people referred to themselves as Earthlings. ;-)

Comment: Hm, I saw the word 'unearthly' for describing something not relating to the Earth. But given 'un-' is negation prefix, I'm sure 'earthly' would be correct.

Comment: If we started a colony on Mars, and the colonists used the word "terrestrial", wouldn't they be referring to "Mars" (or similarly, our Moon, or any other planet or moon) ?

Comment: Nixon's head uses "Earthican", and it goes over well enough to get him reelected multiple times.

Comment: A comment on the "'Earthian' sounds very awkward" line - so does 'Jupitan' or 'Jupitar' (pun not... *entirely* intended), which is why the word for something from Jupiter is "Jovian".  [A longer list of adjectival forms of Stellar Bodies can be found on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_of_astronomical_bodies#Planets)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

[Terrestrial](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/terrestrial):

> - relating  to the earth

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Might be nitpicking here, but I interpret that as meaning, relating to conditions on the surface of the planet, not relating to the planet itself. For instance, one might say: "Terran species can only survive in terrestrial environments", meaning [from-earth] species ... [like-earth] environments.

Comment: @Benubird I don't think so, otherwise the antonym `extraterrestrial ` wouldn't mean also "from outer planets".

Comment: @LorenzoDonati It doesn't. It means not from earth. extra = from-somewhere-other-than, terrestrial = the-environment-of-earth. Try comparing it to a term for another planet: extramartian does not make sense, the same way extraterran doesn't make sense. If terrestrial/martian matched earth/mars, then extraterrestrial/extramartian would also fit, but they don't.

Comment: @Benubird: It certainly can mean what you say; but it can also mean what the question asks for.  In some contexts it can mean other things still: e.g. in zoology you can distinguish *terrestrial* animals (ground-dwelling) from *arboreal* (tree-dwelling), *aquatic*, etc.  It’s not at all unusual for a word to have several related but slightly different meanings!

Comment: @Benubird Well, sorry but I don't agree in general. The meaning of a word may be context-dependant. Try going to a Sci-Fi convention and ask everybody what do they mean by "extraterrestrial".  Moreover "extramartian" is sometimes used to mean "not from the planet Mars", as you can see in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_(rover)): `Mission highlights include the initial 90 sol mission, finding extramartian meteorites such as Heat Shield Rock...`

Comment: @LorenzoDonati You're contradicting yourself. Extraterrestrial means not from earth, as said. Extramartian means not from mars, as you said. It doesn't matter how many people are wrong at a convention. Facts are facts, and this is the right answer.

Comment: @i-CONICA Sorry, but you are barking at the wrong tree. Please, re-read the stream of comments. I never objected to this answer. On the contrary, I supported this answer. In fact, I mildly objected to the objection of Benubird, that nitpicked (in his own words) about the meaning of "terrestrial" vs. "terran".

Comment: You bark up the wrong tree, not at it. :) If that’s the case, then fair enough, but your comment about it meaning “from outer planets” is isn’t correct. It doesn’t mean from outer planets, it just means not from earth, be they from another planet, near or far or just floating in space.

Comment: @i-CONICA Thank you for correcting my idiom ("at" vs. "up"). As for your other objection, please, re-read carefully what I said. I said "***also*** from outer planets". I didn't want to explain every and single meaning of that word. I just wanted to point out that Benubird wasn't spot-on with his nitpicking because in *at least another context*, ***for example***, it meant "from outer planets" (as in some sci-fi movie, like ET). I thought it was clear enough that I wasn't trying to explain all the nuances, but *only to give a **single, context-specific counterexample***.

Comment: as a non-native speaker my intuition suggested "terranean", probably because of "subterranean". Looking it up, [MW lists it](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terranean) as a synonym.

Comment: @PLL I've always said sloths are aliens.

Answer (score 81):

Earth is "Terra". The corresponding adjective would be "Terran".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra

"Terran" can be used for a person or life-form from Earth, to contrast them from those from other planets or places. Taking the intention from the title of the question, an `earth-based` life-form (as opposed to one from Mars) would be "terran".

"Terrestrial" is more used to distinguish things that are on the ground to distinguish them from things that are in the water ("aquatic") or airborne. Hence "terrestrial snakes", "terrestrial travel".

I would say "earth-based" in most cases would be "terran", but that in the case of eclipse, "terrestrial" is more conventional.

Comment: "Terran" refers to creatures, plants, and so forth native to the planet Earth.  "Terrestrial" refers to things more directly *of* the planet Earth.  "Terrestrial eclipse" versus "Terran insects".

Comment: Terran isn't even listed in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english?q=terran), and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Terran) defines it as "earthman". [Oxford online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/terran) defines it as *"(in science fiction) an inhabitant of the earth"*. And yet, it seems to me "terran" **is** used in this context (more than just people) in science fiction, so eventually it may enter the lexicon.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary gives 2 senses for terran, the first of which is indeed "_(Science Fiction.) adj.  Of or pertaining to the planet Earth or its inhabitants._", attested as early as 1881 (under the variant spelling Terrane), no less.

Comment: Yeah, Eureka should remove their self-flagellating note and just clarify. The answer to the original question is 'Terran', particularly in SF discussions of comparative lifeforms, and 'terrestrial' is what you'd use for the eclipse in the second question.

Comment: If you wish to include terms common in science fiction then consider Tellus/Tellurian as well.  However, terrestrial seems the obvious choice here.

Comment: Yes, Earth is indeed Terra.

Answer (score 43):

As [user110518's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/450308/102510) states, *terrestrial* is the required adjective. However, attacking the "eclipse" angle...

A [**Solar eclipse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse) is when we cannot see the Sun (because the Moon is in the way):

```
      /     \            ____                                  /
     /       \          /    \                                |
    |  Earth  | ==>    | Moon |                               |   Sun
     \       /          \____/                                |
      \     /                                                  \
```

A [**Lunar eclipse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_eclipse) is when we cannot "see" the Moon (because the earth [mostly] blocks the Sun's light from reaching it):

```
      ____            /     \                                  /
     /    \          /       \                                |
    | Moon |    <== |  Earth  |                               |   Sun
     \____/          \       /                                |
                      \     /                                  \
```

From these, we can take it that an ***X* eclipse** is when we cannot (fully) see "***X***" because *something* (unspecified) is in the way.

Thus, someone on the Moon as the Earth passes between it and the Sun (the arrangement *we* call a *lunar eclipse*) would experience a **Solar eclipse** (because the Sun is blocked):

```
      ____            /     \                                  /
     /    \          /       \                                |
    | Moon | ==>    |  Earth  |                               |   Sun
     \____/          \       /                                |
                      \     /                                  \
```

The reference that [Sven Yargs](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/36232/sven-yargs) pointed out in a comment, [The Observer's Guide to Planetary Motion](https://books.google.com/books?id=1kUkBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&dq=%22terrestrial+eclipse%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgrYfe29LbAhVrwFQKHVQ7AeEQ6AEISzAG#v=onepage&q=%22terrestrial%20eclipse%22&f=false), 2014 by Dominic Ford confirms this [emphasis mine]:

> As seen from the Moon, the Earth's disk appears to pass in front of the Sun at a lunar eclipse. [...] It is rather curious to think that what we on Earth call a **lunar eclipse** might reasonably be called a **solar eclipse** by an inhabitant of the Moon.

He (Dominic Ford) then goes on to introduce the term **terrestrial eclipse**, *but* I think he does so incorrectly [emphasis again mine]:

> Likewise, what we call a **solar eclipse** on Earth might reasonably be called a **terrestrial eclipse** on the Moon. If our hypothetical lunar inhabitant were to see a partial solar eclipse—the Earth's disk partially covering the Sun—then the part of the Moon's surface beneath his feat would lie within the Earth's penumbra. However, if he were to see a total solar eclipse—the Earth entirely covering the Sun's disk—then he would be standing within the Earth's umbra.

The problem is that although he starts talking about a solar eclipse *from the Earth's perspective* (where the Moon is in the middle; 1st diagram), the remainder of the paragraph describes a solar eclipse *from the Moon's perspective* (when the *Earth* is in the middle; 3rd diagram). This arrangement, we have already agreed, is a *solar eclipse* because the view of the Sun (from the Moon) is blocked.

One *plausible* definition of a **terrestrial eclipse** *would* use the same arrangement that we (on Earth) call a *solar eclipse*:

```
      /     \            ____                                  /
     /       \          /    \                                |
    |  Earth  |    <== | Moon |                               |   Sun
     \       /          \____/                                |
      \     /                                                  \
```

In the same way as a *lunar eclipse* is where light falling on the Moon is (partially) blocked by the Earth we're standing on; here, a *terrestrial eclipse* would be where someone on the Moon, looking at the Earth, sees [a small] part of it obscured by the Moon *they* are standing on.

However, just as a full solar eclipse (where the Moon *completely* blocks the Sun) can only be seen from a small area of the Earth; here, only a small area of the earth would be dimmed by the Moon: it is, perhaps, only *technically* an eclipse.

The other definition of a **terrestrial eclipse** – and one only very recently available – would be where the observer's view of the Earth is blocked by something else. This would never have been visible from the Moon (there's nothing large-enough between the Moon and the Earth to get in the way): it is only recently<sup>**1**</sup> that space-probes have offered us such a view (although this is still only a *partial* terrestrial eclipse:

```
      /     \            ____                                 +--------+
     /       \          /    \                                |DSCOVR  |
    |  Earth  |        | Moon |                           <== |L1 point|
     \       /          \____/                                +--------+
      \     /
```

---

<sup>**1**</sup> The most recent, and (presumably) best images of this are available on NASA's [From a Million Miles Away, Moon Crossing Face of Earth](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/696/from-a-million-miles-away-moon-crossing-face-of-earth/) page. There, it also notes that NASA's Deep Impact spacecraft captured a similar view in 2008, but only from a distance of 31 million miles.

Comment: +10! A great explanation!  And the ASCII diagrams are a nice touch too. :-)

Comment: Excellent answer. There is a nice diagram of various eclipses from various viewpoints in G.F. Schilling & R.C. Moore, "[Eclipse Observation](https://books.google.com/books?id=upvsCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA88&dq=%22terrestrial+eclipse%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjai_zf_9TbAhVLlFQKHcBsCksQ6AEIOzAD#v=onepage&q=%22terrestrial%20eclipse%22&f=false)," in _Proceedings of the First Lunar International Laboratory (LIL) Symposium_ (1966). The authors write,"Note that someone on the Moon would be observing a _solar eclipse_ when we on Earth would be observing a lunar eclipse. Similarly ...

Comment: ...a _terrestrial eclipse_ —really a lunar shadow transit—is seen from the Moon when a solar eclipse is observed on earth." So, according to Schilling & Moore, a more accurate descriptive term for **terrestrial eclipse**, if you are talking about the view from the Moon, is **lunar-shadow transit**.  (And as I mentioned earlier, the illustrations on page 88 of the paper are quite clear and well labeled.)

Comment: Your drawings are really great!

Comment: Why you keep repeating "the Earth"? Nobody says "the Mars". If you are to capitalize Earth as a proper noun, then it is simply Earth, and alternatively, "the earth" which applies to the "ground made of dirt", i.e soil, which can be found on planets other than Earth.

Comment: @dtech Because (a) it seemed right at the time and (b) probably (at least subconsciously) because that's how _The Observer's Guide to Planetary Motion_ book did it (although now I see the recommended practice seems to be to use "Earth" or "the earth". I'll probably edit in the info about the lunar-shadow transit when I get a chance; if I do, I'll review "the Earth"s.

Comment: And to belabor the point, "Moon" is also wrong for the same reason. And the correct format would be "the moon" - "moon" is a common noun, and the proper noun for the moon that orbits Earth is Luna. And the name of "the sun" or star that our planet orbits is Sol. Which also makes it wrong to refer to other stellar systems as "solar" or even "Solar", and also that it is always capitalized when you write "Solar eclipse" or "Lunar eclipse", much like "Martian atmosphere" - the first two - commonly mistaken even in academic literature. Overall literacy in that aspect is surprisingly low.

Comment: @dtech "Overall literacy in that aspect is surprisingly low." -> A descriptivist might instead suggest that overall *consistency* or *application of logic* in that aspect is low. For instance, using the Latin "Luna" as a name for Earth's moon may be an elegant way of making the distinction, but the use of "the Moon" with definite article and capital M commonly and unambiguously serves the same purpose. Arguably, calling your local moon "the moon" is just the same as calling your local urban centre "the town" or "the city".

Comment: @IMSoP application of logic is low in all aspects in general :) Oddly enough, I have never heard anyone say "I am going to the town" unless it is followed by a "of ParticularName", and I've never heard "I am going to city" - it is always "to town" and "to the city". I guess since cities are larger and fewer, thus more prominent, the more appropriate form is to particularize it, even if the particular name is not mentioned., whereas towns are somehow less relevant. Although "village" breaks that logic, likely due to verbal tradition of secluded dwellers seeing the village as the major thing.

Answer (score 14):

It's always '[terrestrial](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/450308/171986)' with reference to an eclipse. For what it's worth, 'earthian' isn't the adjectival form of 'earth', though. The actual words are

## [Earthly](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/59047)

> (*attest. from OE*) Of or relating to earth or Earth, *variously*
>
> - Restricted to Earth; *hence* non-spiritual, material; *hence* worldly, base, coarse.
> - On Earth; *hence* (*obs.*) on or in the ground *or* (*in quest. & neg., esp. before 'no' or 'any'*) in any possible way.
> - (*arch.*) Made of earth.
> - Like earth; *hence* (*arch.*) ready for a tomb, pale and lifeless.
> - (*chiefly SF*) From Earth or resembling sth from Earth.
> - (*n., in plural*) Earthly things or people.
> - (*n., UK colloq.*) An earthly chance.

## [Earthling](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/59045)

> (*attest. from OE*) A being of the earth, *variously*
>
> - (*obs.*) A farmer.
> - (*obs.*) Some kind of bird, now uncertain.
> - (*Xian.*) A person dwelling upon the earth.
> - (*now chiefly SF*) A person from Earth.
> - (*arch.*) A materialistic person.

## [Earthy](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/59064)

> (*attest. a. 1400*) Of or relating to earth, Earth, or (*chem.*) the earths, *variously*
>
> - Like earth; *hence* (*minerol.*) lusterless, friable, rough, &/or uneven *or* (*elec.*) similar in potential to the ground *or* (*now chiefly pseudosci.*) heavy, material; *hence* (*esp. of humor*) unrefined, crude; *hence* unpretentious, down-to-earth.
> - Made of earth; *hence* (*now chiefly pseudosci.*) restricted by its earthy composition, gross.
> - Covered with, full of, or containing earth; *hence* dirty.
> - On Earth; *hence* on or (*esp.*) in the ground.
> - (*uncommon*) Terrestrial.
> - Restricted to Earth; *hence* non-spiritual, material; *hence* worldly

## [Earthish](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/59039)

> (*attest. c. 1533*; *now chiefly SF*) Earthly, of earth.

## [Earthite](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/59040)

> (*attest. 1814*; *now chiefly SF*) A person from Earth.

Also **[earth-bred](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/59023#eid139704829)** and **[-born](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/59028)**; their latinate equivalents **[terrigenous](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/199588)** and **[terrigenal](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/199586)**; and, *only* dealing with things made of, like, or restricted to earth, **[earthen](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/59030)**.

Answer (score 11):

Little used these days, but another name for the planet is Tellus, and its adjective form is Tellurian. For what it is worth.

Comment: Even though the name ends in -us, usually associated with masculine-gendeer nouns in Latin, Tellus was a Roman earth-goddess, the counterpart of the Greek earth-goddess Gaia.

Comment: "Tellurian" was used in this sense by E E "Doc" Smith in the very early days of genre science fiction, before a literary convention had developed around the use of "Terran".

Comment: @tautophile *tellūs,  tellūris* (long *u*) is a 3rd-declension noun, which means the gender is less predictable from the ending. As it happens, the common noun *tellūs* is feminine, and means *earth, ground, land*, as well as being used as a name for the goddess.

Answer (score 6):

"terrestrial" literally means "having to do with the Earth", but can also be used in a more metaphorical sense of contrasting with ethereal, spiritual, etc. "terran" in another option.

However, if we're talking about eclipses, the naming conventions are highly dependent on point of view. When the Earth's shadow falls on the moon, we call that a "lunar" eclipse. When the moon's shadow falls on Earth, we call that a "solar" eclipse. So in the first case, the eclipse is named according to what body the shadow is on, and in the second case, it's named according to what body the shadow is from. The naming is highly Earth-centric: when we see a change in the moon's appearance, we call that a "lunar" eclipse, and when we see a change in the sun's appearance *from Earth's point of view*, we call that a "solar" eclipse. If you were on the moon, a "solar" eclipse would look like a terrestrial eclipse, and a "lunar" eclipse would look like a solar eclipse.

Comment: "but can also be used in a more metaphorical sense of contrasting with ethereal, spiritual, etc. "terran" in another option."

A better word for that is 'mundane'.

Answer (score 5):

**tellurian** perhaps from *tellus* which is a Latin word for Earth, 
**gaian** from Gaia another word for earth ?

> **tellurian**
>   tɛˈljʊərɪən formal literary
>
> *adjective*
>   1. of or inhabiting the earth.
>
> *noun*
>   1. an inhabitant of the earth.

*Tellurian* is used in [*E.E. "Doc" Smith*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._E._Smith)'s science fiction novels

Answer (score 4):

When either Mercury or Venus is seen to cross the disk of the Sun, that is called a "transit" of the planet.  The disk of the planet is very small compared to the disk of the sun, so it doesn't qualify as an "eclipse"  Arthur C Clarke wrote a story called "Transit of Earth" [1971], where the Earth (and the Moon, I think) crossed the disk of the Sun as seen from Mars...and the transit of Earth in the story will really occur on the date the story was set (2084).  The most recent transit of Earth as seen from Mars took place in 1984, but nobody was there to see it.  When the Moon or a planet passes in front of a star or other celestial body as seen from Earth, that is an "occultation".  There are photos taken from satellites of the Moon's shadow moving across the Earth during a solar eclipse.  I suppose if you were on the Moon, and the Earth was between you and the Sun, you  might call it a "Terran eclipse", but people on Earth would call it a lunar eclipse.

Comment: This is interesting comment about eclipses. But can you emphasize the part where you give the 'Earth' version of lunar and solar?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, Mitch, but a solar eclipse (as seen from the Earth) is one where the Moon's shadow is cast on the Earth.  A lunar eclipse (as seen from the Earth) is one where the Earth's shadow is cast on the Moon.  In a total solar eclipse, the sun is completely blotted out for observers on Earth for a short time.  This enables us to see the solar corona, which is otherwise blotted out by the sun's glare.  In a total lunar eclipse, the Earth's atmosphere refracts enough sunlight to the Moon that the Moon never quite disappears from sight to observers on the Earth.

Comment: Tautophile, the OP is about the word for the earth that is analogous to lunar and solar. You've done a lot of  explanation of astronomy which is very interesting but mostly irrelevant. In the end you suggest 'terran' as the word. All I'm saying is that you should somehow emphasize that suggestion rather than emphasize all  the astronomy.

Comment: You've got a point there, Mitch.  It occurs to me that, if you're on the Moon and the Earth comes between you and the Sun, that's a solar eclipse from your point of view, but a lunar eclipse from the point of view of your colleague back on Earth.  If you're on the Moon and the Moon comes between the Sun and the Earth, you might call what you see a "terran" (or terrestrial or tellurian or maybe even simply an Earth) eclipse, but to your earthbound colleague, it would be a solar eclipse.  "It's all how you look at it."